# Pattern String from a joda-time DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, jodatime

Is it possible to get the pattern string from a joda-time DateTimeFormatter?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
String originalPattern = formatter. ???
```

Comment: I assume you're looking to get `"yyyyMMdd"` back? In your particular example, you could just declare a separate `String` variable. Is there a reason that won't suffice?

Comment: @MattBall, almost certainly because this is just a simplified example to illustrate the problem.  The question itself is clear enough.

Comment: FYI, similar Question for java.time: [Get original pattern String given a JDK 8 DateTimeFormatter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28949179/642706). The java.time classes supplant the Joda-Time project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Joda Time does not provide a way to get the original pattern from a DateTimeFormatter. One reason is probably that a DateTimeFormatter wasn't necessarily created from a pattern; for example `DateTimeFormat.forStyle()` does not use patterns at all.

However if you always use patterns, then you could wrap the `DateTimeFormat` class to record the pattern when the `DateTimeFormatter` is constructed. That way you can look it up later with a simple static method. For example:

```
public class ReversableDateTimeFormat {

  private static final Map<DateTimeFormatter, String> patternHistory = new HashMap<DateTimeFormatter, String>();

  public static DateTimeFormatter forPattern(String pattern) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
    patternHistory.put(dateTimeFormatter, pattern);
    return dateTimeFormatter;
  }

  public static String getPattern(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {
    return patternHistory.get(dateTimeFormatter);
  }

}
```

Then you can do this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ReversableDateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
String originalPattern = ReverseableDateTimeFormat.getPattern(formatter);
```

Comment: Excellent.  Sometimes, you're just looking for a good old "that's impossible".  A fine solution, too, for the cases where it's applicable.

Comment: The answer is completely right. But, if you want to use styles and know the pattern you can use `DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle()`.