# Get original pattern String given a JDK 8 DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

Related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947664/where-are-the-java-8-datetimeformatters-constants-defined) - how do I get the original `pattern` String given a `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Likely not a duplicate, as this is about the JDK 8 DateTimeFormatter class, not the joda time class

Comment: @bowmore The JDK 8 DateTimeFormatter class was based off the JodaTime DateTimeFormatter class. The answers to that question are the answers to this question.

Comment: @KevinWorkman That one inspired the other, does not make them the same. Their behaviour is different in various ways. Nevertheless, while the answers may be the same, the question is not a duplicate, as the one asking the question may be unaware of the relation between the two.

Comment: I clearly specified that it is the JDK  8 one. The question you marked this a duplicate of is the joda one.

Comment: @bowmore and wrick: The answer is the same. This isn't possible, for the reasons outlined in the duplicate. Interesting question though.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: So the answer is duplicate and the not the question :)

Comment: @wrick I'll let others decide. I just pointed out the duplicate, since it's what showed up on a google search, and it contains the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Why do you need the pattern anyway, wrick?

Comment: @bowmore: See the link from my question. Posting it again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947664/where-are-the-java-8-datetimeformatters-constants-defined

My end-goal is to extract the string constants like `"YY"` given a `ChronoField` and `TextStyle`. There seems to be no way of doing that unless I want to use reflection to dig into a private field of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` or unless there is a way to extract a pattern from a `DateTimeFormatter` itself.

Comment: Ok, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: @bowmore: I am trying to infer the date format given a date snippet. See: http://thechangelog.com/date-time-formatting-humans/
Why am I doing that? Because seems like an interesting thing to do and don't think there's a JDK8 library that already does that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's been asked [on the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/threeten-dev/2015-March/001611.html) and the answer is that it is not possible because the original pattern is not retained.

The same thread suggests using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` which does have the information.

Comment: I guess `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` allows to build localized format, but doesn't exactly give out the exact format used for building the `DateTimeFormatter` object, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @RohitJain That's probably the case - the javadoc doesn't promise giving back the original pattern.

Answer (score 6):

It may not be a direct answer to your question but it may help.

If you know the parameters of how it the formatter was constructed you can call the static method:

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle dateStyle, FormatStyle timeStyle, Chronology chrono, Locale locale)`

This will give you the pattern as a string.

Comment: Or more simply: `((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.FRENCH)).toPattern()`

Answer (score 2):

Not a straightforward or elegant solution, but using the results of the `DateTimeFormatter`'s `.toString()` method, it might be possible to roll your own code that parses out the resulting String and reconstructs the original pattern.

Some code that prints a few `.toString()` results for various patterns:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter variousFormatPatterns =
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy MM dd");
System.out.println("Test 1: " + variousFormatPatterns.toString() );

variousFormatPatterns = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd");
System.out.println("\nTest 2: " + variousFormatPatterns.toString() );

variousFormatPatterns = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd");
System.out.println("\nTest 3: " + variousFormatPatterns.toString() );

variousFormatPatterns = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("\nTest 4: " + variousFormatPatterns.toString() );
```

Results (note the retention of the space/hyphen/slash/colon delimiter characters):

> Test 1: ReducedValue(YearOfEra,2,2,2000-01-01)' 'Value(MonthOfYear,2)' 'Value(DayOfMonth,2)
>
> Test 2: ReducedValue(YearOfEra,2,2,2000-01-01)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)
>
> Test 3: ReducedValue(YearOfEra,2,2,2000-01-01)Value(MonthOfYear,2)Value(DayOfMonth,2)
>
> Test 4: Value(MonthOfYear,2)'/'Value(DayOfMonth,2)'/'Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)' 'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)

Implementing this approach would require studying the code in `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.  The JavaDoc for the `appendPattern(String pattern)` method appears to be particularly useful.  You might be able to take some shortcuts if you know you are working with only a few types of patterns.

Taking a quick glance through the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` code, there would likely be a risk relying on this type of solution as the Strings such as `Value`, `ReducedValue`, `Fraction`, etc. could change without notice in future Java versions.