# Format string for java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, datetimeformatter

In Java 8's `java.time` package, there is this formatter

`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT))

which allows for optional fractional second in parsing and formatting

> The ISO instant formatter that formats or parses an instant in UTC,
>   such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'.
>
> This returns an immutable formatter
>   capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 instant format. When
>   formatting, the second-of-minute is always output. The nano-of-second
>   outputs zero, three, six or nine digits digits as necessary. When
>   parsing, time to at least the seconds field is required. Fractional
>   seconds from zero to nine are parsed. The localized decimal style is
>   not used.

What is the format string that can be used to create this formatter?  I need to store the `String` but not the `DateTimeFormatter` because the latter is not serializable.

Specifically, I want to know how to express the fractional seconds (including the `.` that precedes the numbers). I know `S` is for fraction-of-second, and `X` is for zone-offset, but I don't how to put them together

```
S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
```

Comment: I don't think there is any pattern able to reproduce this formatting. You'll have to use some magic value (like "ISO_INSTANT"), or an additional field, to store the formatter. Note that fraction (S) doesn't do what the iso formatter does. It displays as few digits as possible, not 0, 3, 6 or 9

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly, brackets can be used to denote an optional part of some formatting string, in some contexts. I see if I can find it.

Comment: Voting to clase as unclear. Half of the import details are presented in an Answer rather than in the Question.

Comment: @JBNizet is correct, this is not possible. You may study the source code: it relies on some internal workings of a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` that we don’t have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the direct equivalent format pattern string.  As @JB Nizet has suggest, this may not even be possible.

However, I found that I can use the optional section markers `[` and `]` in the `String` pattern to get an approximate behaviour:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]X"
```

This can handle the following input strings:

```
"2019-09-02T12:38:16Z"
"2019-09-02T12:38:16.294Z"
```

This makes the fractional-second component optional.

However, for me there is still a limitation -- the fractional second, while now optional, must be exactly  3-digit if present.  I don't know what is the `String` pattern that can make the `DateTimeFormatter` accept 0-9 fractional second digits.

To overcome this limitation, now I use the following solution -- any fractional-second component, if present, are to be first "canonicalized" into 3 digits.  This
is done via a method `optionalCanonicalizeFractionalSecond()` (code shown below) before the input string is passed into a `DataTimeFormatter` for parsing.  This
method works for me so far.

So given `mm:ss[.SSS]` as part of the input pattern:

```
`12:30.123`       will be canon'ed as `12:30.123`
`12:30.12`        will be canon'ed as `12:30.120`
`12:30.1`         will be canon'ed as `12:30.100`
`12:30.123456789` will be canon'ed as `12:30.123`
```

**Example Code**

```
/*
 * Apparently java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter cannot handling
 * a string pattern with variable number of fractional-second
 * digitit.  This method "canonicalize"  any such component
 * to 3 digits
 */
private String optionalCanonicalizeFractionalSecond(String input) {
    if (!formatPattern.contains("mm:ss[.SSS]")) {
        // no fractional-second component in the pattern
        return input; // no need to make any changes
    }
    Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)(\\d\\d:\\d\\d)(\\.\\d+)(.*)$");
    Matcher matcher = regexPattern.matcher(input.trim());
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        // no fractional-second componet in the input string
        return input;
    }
    String prefix = matcher.group(1);
    String minuteSecondString = matcher.group(2);
    String fractionalSecondString = matcher.group(3);
    String suffix = matcher.group(4);
    String canonFss;
    if (fractionalSecondString.length() == 2) {
        canonFss = fractionalSecondString + "00";           // padding with 00
    } else if (fractionalSecondString.length() == 3) {
        canonFss = fractionalSecondString + "0";            // padding with 0
    } else if (fractionalSecondString.length() == 4) {
        canonFss = fractionalSecondString;                  // as is
    } else if (fractionalSecondString.length() > 4
        && fractionalSecondString.length() <= 10) {
        canonFss = fractionalSecondString.substring(0,4);   // truncate to 3 digits
    } else {
        return input;
    }
    return prefix + minuteSecondString + canonFss + suffix;
}
```

Comment: These inputs represent different animals. The first two lack the context of an offset-from-UTC or time zone, so they should be parsed as `LocalDateTime` objects. The third represents a moment, a point on the timeline, in UTC specifically. It should be parsed as an `Instant`.

Comment: @Basil -- I agree with you.  I have changed my answer about and removed the irrelevant part of the discuasion about optional offset. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I could find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496328/7859515). However, I don't know / can't find any way to get the 0/3/6/9 digit decimal behavior.

I'd urge you to consider if you're solving the right problem, namely: *why* do you need to serialize the formatter itself? The formatter is not data, it's logic. Serialize your data, and just use a consistent formatting scheme across the project - you can even centralize time serialization / deserialization so that classes that read/write don't actually need to bother with formatting at all.

The alternative is to find a way to serialize the formatter and put the burden on every reader and writer to record and interpret the formatter used for a serialized time. You're resigning yourself to hard dependencies on formatting shared among all the classes involved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am using Apache Spark and am dealing with code with parameterized formats.  I cannot send `DateTimeFormatter` because it is not serializable so I am sending only the format pattern, and let the formatter be instantiated after the code has arrived at the worker nodes.