# Retrieve date format pattern from current Locale

Tags: java, date

I would like to retrieve the current date format. Not formatted date, what I need is format such as `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy` depending on the current Locale. I've a validation that checks if the user entered correct date from the input that is adjusted to his country.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
String format = ((SimpleDateFormat)dateFormat).toPattern();
System.out.println(format); // M/d/yy
```

as you can see above the output is different than I would like to see, I do not understand why it returns this format instead of `MM/dd/yyyy` in that case, any ideas how can I retrieve the pattern for current locale?

Comment: But `M/d/yy` is the correct answer, for the "short" date format for USA.  Did you try `DateFormat.MEDIUM` or `DateFormat.LONG`?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem then how could I retrieve the pattern such as `MM/dd/yyyy` from above code?

Comment: DId you try using `DateFormat.MEDIUM` or `DateFormat.LONG` instead of `DateFormat.SHORT` on the first line?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes but it adds "," signs after current day in case of UK format.

Comment: So you're claiming that in _some_ locales, the built-in formats are incorrect?  That sounds like something you could take up with Oracle.  Or just add code to remove unwanted commas.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem for UK with `DateFormat.MEDIUM` the output is `dd-MMM-yyyy` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy` not sure why.

Comment: @Sdf19 `MEDIUM` is longer than `SHORT`, hence the longer month name. If you want short, use `SHORT`.

Comment: @Sdf19 You should probably explain why do you need to know the format. To me it looks like interesting question in cases where I would like to show user what date format should he use (and make it based on locale)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this:  [*Get original pattern String given a JDK 8 DateTimeFormatter?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28949179/642706)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    input , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )
                     .withLocale( Locale.sytemDefault() ) 
)
catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) { … }
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

First, you are using terrible classes that were outmoded years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Just parse it

> I've a validation that checks if the user entered correct date from the input that is adjusted to his country.

You do not need to know the format beforehand. If you want to see if the user entered data appropriate to the format expected by the current default `Locale`, just try parsing. If the parsing fails, you know the input was incorrect.

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class can determine automatically the localized format appropriate to a particular locale.

```
Locale locale = Locale.sytemDefault() ;   
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
try 
{ 
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) 
{
    … handle the situation of faulty input
}
```

Actually, the `.withLocale` call is redundant here. If you do not specify a locale, the JVM’s current default `Locale` is implicitly applied. I made the code explicit, as I suggest you do too, to make our intentions clear and obvious.

## Alternatives

Someone commented:

> So you're claiming that in some locales, the built-in formats are incorrect?

You should understand that localization is a complicated subject. Even within a particular culture, opinions may vary as to what conventions are appropriate.

Be aware that in version 9 of Java, at least those implementations using OpenJDK, [switched the source](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) of localization details. OpenJDK now uses the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium)'s [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository). So some behaviors and formats may be different than seen in earlier versions.

On top of all that, conventions change and evolve over time.

So the upshot: Consider asking the user what is their preferred format. Offer a list to choose from. Store their desired format as a preference setting.

Comment: `You do not need to know the format beforehand` - for parsing yes. What if I want user to know what format to use? Can `java.time` API return date format somewhere?

Comment: @Piro If you want to tell the user which format to use, why do you care about the current default locale set on their machine? The whole point to using their default locale is to *not* tell them what format to use. Your overall question makes no sense to me. As for the narrow question about getting the format of the localized date, no I do not know of any. Though I do recall this being asked before, so perhaps someone found a way on that previous question.

Comment: @BasilBouque while user will probably enter date in current locale, he should not guess. Just UX hint

Comment: @Piro Ahhh, I see now. That *does* make sense. I am certain the question of “get the format from a `DateTimeFormatter`”, in other words the opposite of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( … )`, has been asked before on Stack Overflow. I have searched today, but have not found it. I am not sure if a solution was posted there or not.

Comment: Found one! [*Get original pattern String given a JDK 8 DateTimeFormatter?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28949179/642706). Your Question here is likely a duplicate of that one, but I am too tired now to make that judgement call.

Answer (score 2):

I find your requirements contradictory and impossible. At best you’re trying to misuse the built-in localized formats.

If you want a localized format for the US locale, use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern()`:

```
    String dateFormatPattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder
            .getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null,
                    IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.US);
    System.out.println(dateFormatPattern);
```

Output is (tested on JDK 11):

> M/d/yy

Or with `FormatStyle.MEDIUM` instead of `FormatStyle.SHORT`:

> MMM d, y

If on the other hand you want `MM/dd/yyyy`, just specify that directly:

```
    String dateFormatPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Requiring the former code to give the latter result makes no sense. The locale data from CLDR is a best attempt to accommodate the expectations of each culture, and as Basil Bourque says, they are commonly debated. Generally I recommend that you trust CLDR to know the expectations of different cultures better than you do, after all they have done an effort that you will never be able to make on your own. On the other hand, you know your own users better, and it is not that uncommon that we need to hard-code a different format from the built-in one to satisfy our own users.