# Java 8 time/LocalDate: Convert a date from one format to local specific format

Tags: java, java-time, localdate

I get 2 pieces of information from a server call, a date string, and a user locale

```
String originalDateStr = serverCallToGetADate().getDate();
String localeString = serverCallToGetADate().getLocaleString();
```

The date is guaranteed to be in the following format regardless of locale

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

The locale is the IETF language code, such as

```
en-US fr-FR es-ES de-DE etc
```

I can create a LocalDate object for the date using

```
DateTimeFormatter originalFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

LocalDate originalDate = LocalDate.parse(originalDateStr, originalFormatter);
```

I now want to print out the date with just the year as 4 numbers, month as 2 numbers and day as 2 numbers using a "-" in between the values and using the locale string i also received from the server.  For example if the date was 31st July 2021 I want to render the date as

- UK : 31-07-2021
- US : 07-31-2021
- Japan : 2021-07-31

I can not work out how to do this.    This is what I have tried

```
@Test
public void testFormatting() {
    String SERVER_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String SERVER_TEST_DATE = "2021-07-31";

    DateTimeFormatter serverFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(SERVER_FORMAT);
    // can only create a LocalDate from the server value as there is no time part in the string
    LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.parse(SERVER_TEST_DATE, serverFormatter);

    System.out.println("Original Server Date Value = " + testDate.format(serverFormatter));

    System.out.println("\nUsing : testDate.format(serverFormatter.withLocale(locale) - Doesn't work");
    Locale localeUS = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US");
    Locale localeUK = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-GB");
    System.out.println("Attempting US (should be 07-31-2021) = " + testDate.format(serverFormatter.withLocale(localeUS)));
    System.out.println("Attempting UK (should be 31-07-2021) = " + testDate.format(serverFormatter.withLocale(localeUK)));


    // in order to use the following coed these we need a time part for the date, so put to start of day
    System.out.println("\nUsing DateTimeFormatterBuilder - wrong as it includes / or , and has time displayed");
    LocalDateTime testDateTime = testDate.atStartOfDay();
    String datePattern_short = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.MEDIUM, Chronology.ofLocale(localeUS), localeUS);
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatterShort = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern_short);
    System.out.println("datePattern SHORT US (should be 07-31-2021)  = " + testDateTime.format(dateFormatterShort));

    String datePattern_medium = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.MEDIUM, Chronology.ofLocale(localeUS), localeUS);
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatterMedium = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern_medium);
    System.out.println("datePattern MEDIUM US (should be 07-31-2021)  = " + testDateTime.format(dateFormatterMedium));

    String datePattern_long = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.MEDIUM, Chronology.ofLocale(localeUS), localeUS);
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatterLong = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern_long);
    System.out.println("datePattern LONG US (should be 07-31-2021)  = " + testDateTime.format(dateFormatterLong));
}
```

#### Output

```
Original Server Date Value = 2021-07-31

Using : testDate.format(serverFormatter.withLocale(locale) - Doesn't work
Attempting US (should be 07-31-2021) = 2021-07-31
Attempting UK (should be 31-07-2021) = 2021-07-31

Using DateTimeFormatterBuilder - wrong as it includes / or , and has time displayed
datePattern SHORT US (should be 07-31-2021)  = 7/31/21, 12:00:00 am
datePattern MEDIUM US (should be 07-31-2021)  = Jul 31, 2021, 12:00:00 am
datePattern LONG US (should be 07-31-2021)  = July 31, 2021, 12:00:00 am
```

Comment: You can remove `originalFormatter`. The [one-argument LocalDate.parse method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) already handles yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105409/retrieve-date-format-pattern-from-current-locale), where similar to you, that OP also wants a _specific_ format to be spitted out from a method similar to `getLocalizedDateTimePattern`. If you want that specific format, just check for that locale and _write_ that format. If you use someone else's method, they are not going to read your mind. They will spit out whatever _they_ think is the most appropriate. (I also recommend that you trust them if you can.)

Comment: Also, the extra time part is because you converted to `LocalDateTime`s for whatever reason, and supplied a format style for the time. If you stuck with `LocalDate` and used `FormatStyle.NONE`, it would not have the extra time component.

Comment: @Sweeper There does not seem to be a FormatStyle.NONE

Comment: @Sweeper I think you are right, I am wanting to use my own format for the date, rather than the standard format, therefore I should just stick to the standard ones

Comment: @se22as Ah, I remembered wrong. Just pass null if you don't want a time.

Comment: @Sweeper I cant pass null for the time format as there is a non null check on the time format

Comment: What do you mean? That’s literally what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-) says you should do if you don’t want a time. See the parameters section.

Comment: @VGR thank you, I have removed the unecessary code

Comment: @Sweeper Ah my bad, i clearly didnt read the code correctly, i misread a || for && when the code is checking if the formats are present.   This is perfect, and does as close to what i want as possible, it uses / instead of - but i can live with that or do a string replacement.,  

Could you put your response as an answer so i can mark it as the solution

Comment: @Sweeper also now that i am passing null for the time formatting, i can keep my date as a LocalDate and do not need to convert to LocalDateTime.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Sweeper gave the answer in their comments.

What I was trying to do was not valid. I should always use the standard format for the locale's timezone.

Comment: Glad that you found your answer, and thanks for posting it as an answer. You should keep two concepts separate: locale and time zone. Locale controls the format of the date string. Time zone controls the clock hour and ultimately the date. If you visit me in Denmark, you will probably set your device to Europe/Copenhagen time zone, but will keep it at English locale.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why you think you want this and tend to go with Sweeper’s suggestion: You should rather trust that the localized format patterns that Java gets from CLDR (Unicode Common Locale Data Repository) and/or other sources. I don’t imagine that users around the world will be happy about you enforcing a format with hyphens everywhere.

However if you insist, the format pattern string that you get from `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` can be modified to your requirement through a few simpler regular expressions.

```
    String[] tags = { "en-US", "fr-FR", "es-ES", "de-DE", "jp-JP" };
    LocalDate sampleDate = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JULY, 31);
    for (String langTag : tags) {
        Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag(langTag);
        String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
                FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, loc);
        // Ensure full year and 2-digit month and day
        pattern = pattern.replaceAll("y+", "y")
                         .replaceAll("M+", "MM")
                         .replaceAll("d+", "dd");
        // Change punctuation to hyphens
        pattern = pattern.replaceFirst("^\\W+", "")
                         .replaceFirst("\\W+$", "")
                         .replaceAll("\\W+", "-");
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        System.out.format("%-5s -> %s%n", langTag, sampleDate.format(dateFormatter));
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> en-US -> 07-31-2021
> fr-FR -> 31-07-2021
> es-ES -> 31-07-2021
> de-DE -> 31-07-2021
> jp-JP -> 2021-07-31
> ```

I believe that my code will fail to insert a hyphen if two or more fields are adjacent in the pattern, for example `yyMM`. I don’t know whether this occurs for any locale. Also it will not remove any literal letters that are part of the format for some locales. So take it as a starting point and refine to your needs. You may want to test with all available locales in your JVM.

Comment: Yes I agree that what i was wanting was actually incorrect and should do what sweeper said.   Unfortunately i can not set Sweepers comment as the correct answer