# How to test and compare two java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-s?

Tags: java

How to compare two java.time.format.DateTimeFormatters?

Due to the fact that DateTimeFormatters does not have an overridden 'equals' method.

Test:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy").equals(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy"))
```

Result:

```
false
```

This is the behavior of 'Object.equals()' method.
Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

> Methods inherited from class java.lang.Object
> clone, equals, finalize, getClass, hashCode, notify, notifyAll, wait, wait, wait

Use case when it needed:

For example my method returns DateTimeFormatter. And I would like to create test to verify that returned DateFormatter is correct.

For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter expectedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("my custom format")
DateTimeFormatter actualFormatter = someService.getFormatter()
Assert.assertEquals(actualFormatter, expectedFormatter)
```

Comment: "I would like to create test to verify that returned DateFormatter is correct" Then test its behavior, not identity: make sure that it formats dates in the way you expect.

Comment: I doubt that someone who has or had an impact on what is in the code for DateTimeFormatter is going to show up here and answer your question.  Short of that, this question can only illicit answers that are opinions, not facts.  I therefore don't think that this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow, as we try to avoid questions that involve opinions as answers.

Comment: I have fixed title and question.@Rono @Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because determining equality of a formatter is non-trivial, since there are many ways to construct the "same" formatter (in terms of behaviour) via a builder, and is rarely useful.

The JDK developers have finite time. They prioritise the import things. DateTimeFormatter overriding `equals` in a consistent and idiomatic way is much harder than it might seem, they're better off spending time elsewhere.

In any case, it doesn't help you to know why it doesn't exist. That is the situation you are in, and that is not changing any time soon.

My suggestion is to test the *behaviour*. Construct some date (or date-time) and see whether both formatters produce the same output.

```
DateTimeFormatter expectedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("my custom format")
DateTimeFormatter actualFormatter = someService.getFormatter();

LocalDate someFakeDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1);
Assert.assertEquals(actualFormatter.format(someFakeDate), expectedFormatter.format(someFakeDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [ways to obtain the original pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949179/get-original-pattern-string-given-a-jdk-8-datetimeformatter) for comparison.

Since `DateTimeFormatter` is a `final` class that can't be extended, you could replace all your instances with a wrapper class that creates the instance of `DateTimeFormatter` in the constructor and access to the generated `DateTimeFormatter` instance and pass around your custom `DataTimeFormatterContainer` classes in your code.  It's a beast, but it'll do what you are asking.

Of course, this compares exactly the pattern; if two non-identical patterns generate the same result when parsing a date, this will return false.

Barebones proposal; no null checks, accessor methods, or hashcode:

```
public class DateTimeFormatterContainer() {

    public final String pattern;
    public final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public DateTimeFormatterContainer(String pattern) {

        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    }

    public boolean equals(DateTimeFormatterContainer that) {

        return this.pattern.equals(that.pattern);
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, if you find yourself introducing complexity purely for the sake of a test, you should reconsider. Your implementation becomes needlessly restrictive if ever the format is required to diverge from what a pattern can support - the builder can do much more than patterns can.

Comment: As I said, it's a beast, but it'll do what he's asking.