# Get pattern from Java DateTimeFormat to create nice error message

Tags: java, datetime

My app will receive a text string from the client and try to parse it into a `LocalDate`. I want to be able to handle different locales or custom requirements so I don't know which  `DateTimeFormatter` will be used ahead of time.

`LocalDate.parse` might throw an exception. What I want is to generate a nice error message such as

```
Dates must be in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

where the "yyyy-MM-dd" depends on which formatter is being used.

```
    try {
        date = java.time.LocalDate.parse(value, config.getDateFormat());
    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        throw new MyException("Dates must be in format: " + MagicHere);
    }
```

The old `SimpleDateFormat` class has a `toPattern()` method which does what I want. Is there a way to do this with `DateTimeFormatter`?

I have tried `DateTimeFormatter.toString`, but it returns

```
Value(Year,4,10,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)
```

which isn't really user friendly. I didn't see anything useful in `DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949179/get-original-pattern-string-given-a-jdk-8-datetimeformatter

Comment: Sigh. I spent a couple of hours searching. Thanks.

Unfortunately, that question doesn't have a solution. The suggestion is to use DateTimeFormatterBuilder. But
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
String foo = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null, formatter.getChronology(), formatter.getLocale());
gives M/d/yy. Rather than returning the pattern of ISO_LOCAL_DATE it is returning the pattern from the formatter with the same Chronology and locale. In this case the US locale.
Pity.

Comment: You are correct, what you are asking is not possible. Sorry.